Can't select Bold

I have a text in the layout, but can't select the bold option. I can do it through html, but the boldness ins't enough.
What is the problem?
I have the 3.36.1 version.

The problem was that I didn't have the bold character downloaded.

You can set the bold/italic via the style drop down above

Alternatively, you can use the data defined override beside the disabled bold (or italic) button


thanks, but I can't select nor the style nor the data defined override
